# Call button on UI Testing?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I was wondering if it's possible to tap call button from tel's scheme (e.g tel//555555555). Because if I touch call button I'll have an alert that I need to confirm my call or cancel it. Is it possible?

I have this on my code:

```
addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Phone Dialog") { (alert) -> Bool in
        let button = alert.buttons["Llamar"]
        if button.exists {
            button.tap()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    app.tap()
    XCTAssert(app.buttons["call_button"].exists, "No se encuentra el boton de llamar")
    app.buttons["call_button"].tap()
    sleep(2)
```

Any Idea?
Regards

Comment: yes, you can show the alert controller for calling.

Comment: But, how can I identify the call button?

Comment: compare the button title or image for button identification

Comment: Well, I can't tap the "Call" button. Because It seems my UI Test only recognize the buttons inside the app and it seems the "Call" button is outside from my app. @SaurabhJain Do you have any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UIInteractionMonitor` does not work in the case of the phone call system dialog. The phone call dialog is handled by the **Springboard** and not your app.

**Xcode 9** allows you access to the Springboard so you can tap on the "Call" button by doing this:

```
func testPhoneCall() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")

    app.launch()
    app.buttons["call_button"].tap()

    // tap on the call button
    springboard.buttons["Llamar"].tap()

}
```

Comment: Hi @joern, I 've tried to call the interruption Monitor but It couldn't be called. Do u have any idea about the reason of that?

Comment: Have you added the monitor at the beginning of your test before tapping the  phone button? And are you calling `app.tap()` right after adding the monitor?

Comment: above I put my code for testing. However, it still not working. Do u have the reason why?

Comment: You are right. The Monitor does not work in this case. It just worked in my case because of some weird coincidence ;-) I rewrote the answer to make it work.