# Does Automating iphone with Appium Needs license

Tags: ios, iphone, appium

I am using Appium on MAC device to control or automate some iphone functionalities .
lets say to trigger phone call or open camera or swipe ..etc
The question is do i need a developer license ? given that i am not a developer , i just want to control the iphone.
And if i need developer license , should i pay the 99 USD OR i can use the free account for that simple purpose ?
What is did is that i can successfully open camera on ios simulator , but for real device, it gives provisioning profile error.
Thanks

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4952845/3411787) you go.

Answer (score 0):

To test your app on **real device** you need to have a**pple developer provision profile** and sign [WebDriverAgent](https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent) (that Appium use to remote control iOS devices) with it.

You can read about Appium & iOS Real Device configuration [here](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md)

Regarding your notice of triggering phone call & camera: **you can't invoke inbuilt application in iOS using Appium** as it requires the Xcode code signing identity to invoke applications.

If thats what you want to do, you better switch to **[XCUITest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322758/call-button-on-ui-testing)**